# Can anyone help me to solve this problem with NameError: name 'Restaurent' is not defined

Tags: python

This file is restaurent.py and the parent class in my program

```
class Restaurent():
    
    def __init__(self, restaurent_name , cuisine_type,number_served = 0): 
    
        self.restaurent_name = restaurent_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = number_served

    def describe_restaurant(self):

        print(f"Restaurent Name : {self.restaurent_name.title()}")
        print(f"Cuisine Type : {self.cuisine_type.title()}")

   
    def open_restaurant (self):
       print(f"The {self.restaurent_name.title()} is open")
       print(f"Number of customers served : {self.number_served}")

    def set_number_served(self,number_served):
        self.number_served = number_served
        print(f"Number of customers served : {self.number_served}")

    def increment_number_served(self,number_served):
        self.number_served += number_served
        print(f"Increment in number of customers : {self.number_served}")
```

```
import restaurent


class IceCreamStand (Restaurent) : # this is the child class in test.py

    def __init__(self,restaurent_name,cuisine_type,number_served = 0,*flavors) :
        self.flavors = flavors
        super().__init__(restaurent_name,cuisine_type,number_served)
        
    def display_flavors(self) :
     print("Flavors are : ")
     print(self.flavors)


    restaurent = Restaurent('caravan','ice cream',29)

    my_ice = IceCreamStand('vanila','strawberry','butterscotch','hazelnut')

    restaurent.describe_restaurent() # I am not able to call this function in class restaurent

    my_ice.display_flavors()
```

Comment: Note that it's "restaurant". But either `from restaurent import Restaurent` or `import restaurent` and use `restaurent.Restaurent` to refer to the class. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify which "Restaurent" class you mean. specifically you want the one from the module "restaurent", so you need tyo use:

```
class IceCreamStand (restaurent.Restaurent)
```

another approach is to import the class at the top of your file by using:

```
from restaurent import Restaurent
```

Also, it's restaurant (with A). (unless it's intentional wordplay, then nvm :)